# QtTreeWidget stylesheet: change selected item style

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am trying to change the style of the current selected item in a `QtTreeWidget`. Unfortunately, the styling is only applied to the toplevel items and not the toplevel's children. Has anyone encountered this before and have a solution?

The stylesheet works correctly in QtDesigner. I don't know why it doesn't work in my code. I am working on pulling out the code into an example.

---

### stylesheet:

```
QTreeWidget::item:selected { border-color:green; 
    border-style:outset; border-width:2px; color:black; }

QTreeWidget::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeWidget::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
    border-image: none;
    image: none;
    }

QTreeWidget::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeWidget::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
    border-image: none;
    image: none;
    }
```

---

### Complete Example Code

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ConditionTree(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self.tree = parent

        self.setText(0, name)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(name)
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.buttonPress)

    def buttonPress(self):
        self.setExpanded(not self.isExpanded())
        self.tree.setCurrentItem(self)

class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    '''
    Main window class handeling all gui interactions
    '''
    def __init__(self, app):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)

        self.tree.setIndentation(0)
        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(True)

        self.tree.setStyleSheet('''
                                 QTreeWidget::item:selected { border-color:green; 
                                     border-style:outset; border-width:2px; color:black; }
                                 QTreeWidget::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
                                 QTreeWidget::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
                                     border-image: none;
                                     image: none;
                                 }

                                 QTreeWidget::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
                                 QTreeWidget::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
                                     border-image: none;
                                     image: none;
                                 }

                                 ''')

        self.topLevel = ConditionTree(self.tree, 'toplevel')
        self.tree.setItemWidget(self.topLevel, 0, self.topLevel.button)


        for i in range(5):
            self.addNewItem(self.topLevel, str(i))

        self.tree.resize(self.tree.sizeHint())

    def addNewItem(self, toplevel, name):
        newItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
        newItem.setText(0, name)
        newItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

        toplevel.addChild(newItem)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = mainWindow(app)
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()

    app.deleteLater()
    sys.exit()
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child items are not selectable. Since you *cannot* select them, they won't be styled. Modify this line in `addNewItem` method:

```
newItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
```

to

```
newItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
```

Comment: So child items are selectable, just not by default. That fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Onlyjus: No, ``QTreeWidgetItem`` is selectable by default. But you're doing ``setFlags`` on it. That replaces the [default value](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#flags). _Your_ child items are not selectable.